# Combinatorial model for twisted involutions in $S_n$

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $(W,S)$ be a Coxeter group and $*:S \to S$ be an automorphism of the Dynkin diagram of $W$ so that $*^2$ is the identity.
This induces a bijection $*:W \to W$ mapping $w = s_1 \dots s_n$ to $w^* = s_1^* \dots s_n^*$.
We say $y \in W$ is a *twisted involution* if $y^{-1} = y^*$.
Viewing $S_n$ as a Coxeter group generated by simple transpositions, the only choices of $*$ are the identity and the map that sends $s_i = (i,i+1)$  to $s_i^* = s_{n-i}$.
In this setting, we see $y$ is a twisted involution if and only if $y = w_0 y w_0$, i.e., if $y w_0$ is an involution (here $w_0$ is the reverse permutation $n \ n{-1} \dots 1$).

Involutions in the symmetric group $S_n$ have a clear combinatorial description as matchings on the complete $K_n$ (each 2-cycle corresponds to an edge).
This is often depicted graphically:

[image]

corresponds to the involution $(1,10)(2,5)(4,8)(6,11)$.

**Question:** Is there a preferred combinatorial model in the same vein for twisted involutions in the symmetric group?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you expect. For example, the permutation matrix is symmetric with respect to the other diagonal. Put differently, what keeps you from using the same visualisation?